# Vmware Player 7.2.1 unable to find update server

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player

I installed a copy of VMware player 7.2.1. Installation went fine, no errors. Creating a VM also proceeds with no errors, however when I attempt to install VMWare tools I get a message:

> Could not find component on update server. Contact VMware Support or your system administrator.

In checking online, I came across this (old) thead: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/444690 which walks through a process using a hex editor.

I've attempted this with no resolution, and now have a fresh install of player with the same problem.

FWIW, I've used both player as well as workstation successfully since that thread was opened.

Has anyone found a resolution to this that does not involve changing dll files?

[Update]

Installation of Workstation resolves the issue in player.

Comment: Based on my research you would only get this error if there wasn't tools for the guest OS your using.  More information is required.

Comment: @Ramhound - I can reproduce the issue by going to `File -> Preferences -> Download All Components Now` which would download all available tools for local installation later. The virtual machine itself is running Ubuntu 15.04